# bxSlider not working with jquery 2.1.0

Tags: jquery, bxslider

bxSlider uses 1.8.2. and I have to use Jquery 2.1.0 which makes bxSlider not working properly. I you use jquery-2.1.0.js when you click on prev or next button it goes very fast from last to first or from first to last slide.